# Samba file permissions: Linux Server, Mac Client

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, samba

I have Samba running on a Linux server, and access the files from a Mac client. I don't have any problem accessing the files over Samba, except that on the Mac, all files show up with the executable permission set: `rwx------`. On the server, the files are not executable: `rw-rw----`.

Are the permissions shown by the client set on the server or on the client? How can I either:

1. force all files to `rw-------` on the client, or
2. pass the permissions from the server through to the client?

Comment: I want to avoid ACLs, if I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permissions are set **on the server** and are 100% dependent on ACL.

You have two options in order to attempt to solve your issue.

### 1st option (which may better suit your needs): try to map/match Windows and Unix ACLs.

Edit the SMB server's `smb.conf` file and add these parameters to the `[global]` section:

```
[global]
nt acl support = yes
acl map full control = no
```

The two parameters above will cause the SMB server to attempt to map/match Windows and Unix ACLs.

From the `smb.conf` manpage:

> nt acl support (S)
>
> ```
>        This boolean parameter controls whether smbd(8) will attempt to map
>        UNIX permissions into Windows NT access control lists. The UNIX
>        permissions considered are the traditional UNIX owner and group
>        permissions, as well as POSIX ACLs set on any files or directories.
> ```
>
> acl map full control (S)
>
> ```
>        This boolean parameter controls whether smbd(8) maps a POSIX ACE
>        entry of "rwx" (read/write/execute), the maximum allowed POSIX
>        permission set, into a Windows ACL of "FULL CONTROL". If this
>        parameter is set to true any POSIX ACE entry of "rwx" will be
>        returned in a Windows ACL as "FULL CONTROL", is this parameter is
>        set to false any POSIX ACE entry of "rwx" will be returned as the
>        specific Windows ACL bits representing read, write and execute.
> ```

### 2nd option (workaround): set specific ACLs for each one of your shares.

In a nutshell, the RWX (read, write and execute) parameters are defined by these equivalent SMB parameters:

- `writeable = no` is equivalent to R (read only)
- `writeable = yes` is equivalent to RW (read and write)
- `acl allow execute always = true` or `acl allow execute always = yes` is equivalent to X (execute)

In order to set file/folder permissions for all your shares, it's necessary to edit the server's `smb.conf` file and then add this global setting:

```
[global]
acl allow execute always = false
guest ok = no
writeable = yes
available = yes
browseable = yes
printable = no
locking = yes
```

...which will by default force all your shared folders to forbid execution of files (`acl allow execute always = false`), forbid guest access (`guest ok = no`), allow read and edit/(re)write access to files and folders (`writeable = yes`), make all your shares available for use by the remote (client) users (`available = yes`) and make the available shares visible (`browseable = yes`), forbid using your shares as a printing spool directory (`printable = no`), and force locking of your shares if the client sends such request to the SMB server (`locking = yes`).

From the `smb.conf` manpage:

> acl allow execute always (S)
>
> ```
>        This boolean parameter controls the behaviour of smbd(8) when
>        receiving a protocol request of "open for execution" from a Windows
>        client. With Samba 3.6 and older, the execution right in the ACL
>        was not checked, so a client could execute a file even if it did
>        not have execute rights on the file. In Samba 4.0, this has been
>        fixed, so that by default, i.e. when this parameter is set to
>        "False", "open for execution" is now denied when execution
>        permissions are not present.
>
>        If this parameter is set to "True", Samba does not check execute
>        permissions on "open for execution", thus re-establishing the
>        behaviour of Samba 3.6. This can be useful to smoothen upgrades
>        from older Samba versions to 4.0 and newer. This setting is not
>        meant to be used as a permanent setting, but as a temporary relief:
>        It is recommended to fix the permissions in the ACLs and reset this
>        parameter to the default after a certain transition period.
> ```

Note: if `acl allow execute always = false` doesn't work, try `acl allow execute always = no`.

> guest ok (S)
>
> ```
>        If this parameter is yes for a service, then no password is
>        required to connect to the service. Privileges will be those of the
>        guest account.
>
>        This parameter nullifies the benefits of setting restrict anonymous
>        = 2
>
>        See the section below on security for more information about this
>        option.
> ```
>
> writeable (S)
>
> ```
>        Inverted synonym for read only.
> ```
>
> read only (S)
>
> ```
>        An inverted synonym is writeable.
>
>        If this parameter is yes, then users of a service may not create or
>        modify files in the service's directory.
>
>        Note that a printable service (printable = yes) will ALWAYS allow
>        writing to the directory (user privileges permitting), but only via
>        spooling operations.
> ```
>
> available (S)
>
> ```
>        This parameter lets you "turn off" a service. If available = no,
>        then ALL attempts to connect to the service will fail. Such
>        failures are logged.
> ```
>
> browseable (S)
>
> ```
>        This controls whether this share is seen in the list of available
>        shares in a net view and in the browse list.
> ```
>
> printable (S)
>
> ```
>        If this parameter is yes, then clients may open, write to and
>        submit spool files on the directory specified for the service.
>
>        Note that a printable service will ALWAYS allow writing to the
>        service path (user privileges permitting) via the spooling of print
>        data. The read only parameter controls only non-printing access to
>        the resource.
> ```
>
> locking (S)
>
> ```
>        This controls whether or not locking will be performed by the
>        server in response to lock requests from the client.
>
>        If locking = no, all lock and unlock requests will appear to
>        succeed and all lock queries will report that the file in question
>        is available for locking.
>
>        If locking = yes, real locking will be performed by the server.
>
>        This option may be useful for read-only filesystems which may not
>        need locking (such as CDROM drives), although setting this
>        parameter of no is not really recommended even in this case.
>
>        Be careful about disabling locking either globally or in a specific
>        service, as lack of locking may result in data corruption. You
>        should never need to set this parameter.
> ```

Comment: > by default force all your shared folders to forbid execution of files (acl allow execute always = false)

I'm skeptical about that interpretation. That's contrary to the option name and description.

Comment: @Dogweather Indeed, the manpage entry for `acl allow execute always` states _when this parameter is set to "False", "open for execution" is now denied **when execution permissions are not present**._ So, yeah: if the execution permissions **are** present, then `acl allow execute always=false` will **not** prevent "open for execution". Notice, however, that one of the requested solutions in the question is _2. pass the permissions from the server through to the client_ i.e. it suffices if the client respects the execution permissions set in the files that are hosted in the server.

Comment: Neither of these solutions accomplished a thing for me. The first option blocks my access to the files entirely, I can see but do nothing with them. The second allows me to attempt to rename, delete, or edit them, but then coughs up an error afterwards saying I don't have permissions to access them.

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm currently not using MacOS anymore (neither as client nor server), i.e. I'm currently unable to replicate issues experienced with a Linux Samba server and a MacOS Samba client. Anyway, we may try to work around this. I however need more context, like e.g. which Samba version are you running? At the Linux shell, the command `samba -V` lets you know that. Did you restart the Samba server (with either the command `sudo service smbd restart` or `sudo systemctl restart smbd.service`) after the `smb.conf` file was edited/updated? Does your account own explicit access +write permission?

Comment: @JohnSmith Suppose that on your Linux Samba server you ran the command `sudo useradd john` to create a new Linux user account named `john` and then you ran the command `sudo smbpasswd -a john` to set a Samba-specific password for such `john` account, so now you're at your Mac client and want to connect to the Linux Samba server as `john` (you have to provide the Samba-specific password). In this case, at the `[global]` section inside the `smb.conf` file of your Linux server, you have to add these 2 lines: `valid users = john` and `write list = john` (and then restart the Samba service).