# Samba Linux Server: Unable to create/modify/delete on Mac & Windows Client

Tags: permissions, network-shares, samba

While I can connect to the Samba-Share and read all the shared files, I am unable to modify / delete files from that share on my Mac.

I have found a very similar question here: [Samba file permissions: Linux Server, Mac Client](https://superuser.com/questions/1163422/samba-file-permissions-linux-server-mac-client). I tried to the solution from the accepted answer, which is to add to parameters to the `smb.conf`, but unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

My `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
nt acl support = yes
acl map full control = no

security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam
unix charset = utf-8
dos charset = cp932

[private-share]
path = /home/pi/music
valid users = @smbgrp
```

I have given the access rights on the server folder to the `sambauser` and `smbgrp`:

```
sudo chmod -R 0770 /home/pi/music
sudo chown -R sambauser:smbgrp music/
```

Verify this:

```
$ ls -l /home/pi/
total 4
drwxrwx--- 6 sambauser smbgrp 4096 Feb  2 10:19 music
```

When I switch to `sambauser`, I am able to delete files as I like.
Albeit when I switch to my Mac and using `cmd+K` functionality in Finder with the `sambauser`, I can connect to the Samba-Share and read all the shared files, but I am unable to create / modify / delete files from that share on my Mac.

I can also mount it from the command line, but after the mount happened, the folder permissions seem to change:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/samba-share
$ cd /tmp
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  2 hans  wheel   64  2 Feb 14:47 samba-share
$ sudo mount_smbfs //sambauser:password@k3smaster/private-share /tmp/samba-share
$ ls -l
ls: samba-share: Permission denied
$ sudo ls -l
drwx------  1 root       wheel  16384  2 Feb 11:19 samba-share
```

And when I try to delete a file, the permission is denied:

```
$ sudo ls -l samba-share/non-pro/Dan
total 63488
-rwx------  1 root  wheel  5948277  1 Feb 17:05 01-Track-01.mp3
$ sudo rm samba-share/non-pro/Dan/01-Track-01.mp3
override rwx------  root/wheel arch for samba-share/non-pro/Dan/01-Track-01.mp3? y
rm: samba-share/non-pro/Dan/01-Track-01.mp3: Permission denied
```

Same goes for creating files:

```
$ sudo touch samba-share/non-pro/Dan/foo.bar
touch: samba-share/non-pro/Dan/foo.bar: Permission denied
```

Test on Windows client:

```
$ net use z: \\k3smaster\private-share
Windows prompts for username and password
```

After that, the folders and files are accessible but read-only. Same as on Mac.

Comment: Why is Windows prompting for a username and password a problem?  You should be providing the username and password to a username with access to the file.  **This, of course, would not be your Windows username and password**  The linked answer only allows Samba to understand Windows permissions, which is only, one half of the problem with a Samba share on Windows.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, why are you asking whether Windows prompting for a username and password was a problem? I think that's exactly the behavior that is configured in my smb.conf, which is: to establish a connection, the user needs to authenticate. The actual problem is, that after the authentication happens, the access is in read-only.

Comment: Based on your chmod permissions, the only user with write permission is `root`, you are authenticating has the root user of the system which has Samba running?  `samba-share` is owned by `root` with 700 permissions or am I reading those ls output incorrectly?

Comment: So as described above, if I ls -l on the server, this is what I get:

`$ ls -l /home/pi/
drwxrwx--- 6 sambauser smbgrp 4096 Feb  2 10:19 music`

After mounting the share on the client and sudo ls -l on the client, the owner is not sambauser anymore, but as you pointed out, it changes to root. That is basically the issue, I guess. But why this is happening?

`sudo ls -l
drwx------  1 root       wheel  16384  2 Feb 11:19 samba-share`

Comment: Why did you provide us the permissions on `/home/pi`?  Your `samba-share` directory is owned by root with 700 permissions.

Comment: If you look at the smb.conf, you'll notice that this is where the shared folder is located: `[private-share]
path = /home/pi/music` And `samba-share` is just a random name which I chose as the mounting point at the client. It could have been anything. Basically `samba-share` and `/home/pi/music` is the same folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104004/discussion-between-ramhound-and-hans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding both the parameters `read only = no` as well as `writable = yes` seems to do the trick.

The whole `smb.conf`

```
[global]

security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam
unix charset = utf-8
dos charset = cp932
map to guest = Bad Password

[private-share]
path = /home/pi/music
valid users = @smbgrp
read only = no
writable = yes
```

On the Mac client, the permissions of the mounted share are not `root` with group `wheel` anymore. Instead, the owner now is the `logged in Mac user` and group `staff`:

```
$ ls -l /Volumes/samba-share
drwx------  1 hans  staff  16384  1 Feb 18:05 non-pro
```

I am able to create folders and files as well as delete and rename folders and files. So finally it works as it should.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Still get errors whenever I try to save edits to a file on a samba volume.